# isomorphism from finite product of subgroups of $G$ to $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose we are given a *finite* family of normal subgroups $(N_i)_{i\in I}$ of a group $G$. Also, define
$$M_i=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}\left\{a\,\Biggm|\, (\exists y)\left(y\in\left(\bigcup_{k\in I\setminus\{i\}} N_k\right)^n\ \land\ a=y_1...y_n\right)\right\}$$
for every $i\in I$. If I have an isomorphism $\theta$ of $G$ onto $\prod G/M_i$, defined by $\theta(x)=(xM_i)_i$, can I show that $\phi(x):=\prod x_i$, where $x\in \prod N_i$, defines an isomorphism of $\prod N_i$ onto $G$?

Here is my work so far:

*Injection*:

Let $x,y\in\prod N_i$ such that $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$: that is, $\prod x_i=\prod y_i$. Then $\theta(\prod x_i)=\theta(\prod y_i)$. Let $j\in I$: $\theta(\prod x_i)(j)=\prod x_iM_j=x_jM_j$ and $\theta(\prod y_i)(j)=\prod y_iM_j=y_jM_j$. This implies that
$$x_jM_j=y_jM_j\iff y^{-1}_jx_j\in M_j$$
for all $j\in I$. But from this I am not sure how I to deduce $x_j=y_j$. What should I try next?

*Surjection*:

I have no idea how to start this part.

Comment: This is not going to work. What if, say, all $N_i$'s are trivial?

Comment: You never say what $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ are; you never say who the $H_k$ are; your definition does not involve the $N_i$. Please fix your notation.

Comment: So sorry. I fixed the typo.

Comment: You still don't say who the $y_i$ are, and you do nothing with the $y$ other than asking that it be in a certain product. And are the $M_i$ supposed to be $N_i$? Something else? What?

Comment: I wanted $M_i$ to be the subgroup generated by the union $\cup_{k\in I\setminus\{i\}}N_k$, for each $i\in I$. I am sorry that my notation didn't make that clear.

Comment: Okay, the $M_i$ are fine. But what happens to $y$? And what are $y_1,\ldots,y_n$? You say "There exists a $y$, and $a$ is equal to a product of some terms I haven't defined yet".

Comment: $y=(y_j)_{1\leq j\leq n}$ is meant to be a family of elements of $\cup_{k\in I\setminus\{i\}}N_k$.

Comment: That’s not what you have. If $H$ is a subset of a group, then $H^n$ is the subgroup generated by all $n$th powers of elements of $H$. So your $y$, as described, is a product of $n$th powers of elements in the $N_k$, $k\neq i$. It is **not** a tuple, so your expression right now is not what you want it to be. You need to clean this up.